# Rest API filter not taking more than one user and groups column SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have SharePoint online list which has more than 5000 records. I am trying to fetch the data using Rest API and have used 2 User and Groups columns in the filter.

When I try this it says

> 'The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator'

I have used top = 100. but no luck. Can any help me on this?

I have written my query below please check it.

**NOTE:** List view threshold is 5000

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, are you facing any issue related to retrieve number of items? Or Are you facing any issue to retrieve user data?

Comment: I am facing issue with filter if filter has more than one field